# Default language in phonegap / cordova application

Tags: cordova, phonegap-build

I have hybrid mobile application written in `JavaScript` and packaged using [PhoneGap Build](https://build.phonegap.com/). 
Application language is other than English but in *application stores* (Google Play, WindowsMobile store and Apple iTunes Store) it is announced to be in English and users are confused.

Is there any way to tell the PhoneGap Build that application is in a specific language? Maybe some settings in `config.xml`.

Comment: Last time I checked it wasn't possible to change the language with any configuration, you might consider switching to local development

Answer (score 2):

You use the stores themselves to define this.

For example, the Apple store: 
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/Chapters/DisplayInMoreLanguages.html

Comment: that is partially true, the app store page will be shown on the languages you define following your link, but in the app details, the info for "Languages" will be picked from the app binary

Answer (score 0):

@Pavel, the title you used is incorrect. You want to add *Internationalization/Localization Support*, and make that support show up in your app store listing.

Here is your answer:

*Adding Internationalization/Localization Support to Web Applications*
http://www.raymondcamden.com/2012/02/15/Adding-InternationalizationLocalization-Support-to-Web-Applications

You also want to use the term **i18n**

Best of Luck
Jesse

Comment: You probably misunderstood my need. Currently I don't want to translate my app or support multi language. The only thing I want is not to present my app in "app store" as if it is in English when it is in Czech language.

Comment: Okay. Your title is still wrong. You likely want something like: **How can I show my App in the Czech in the App Store?** or **How can I get my App in the Czech section of the App Store?**  -- You should post a new thread. Many people have already by passed this because they read the title and say, "I cannot help"